# How to Use ajax& j Query in spring

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am new to Spring with AJAX.

My requirement is to check whether email is registered or not, when user clicks on check availability. I am successfully making calls to the controller class but the response is displayed in the browser instead of in same jsp and not entering the success block. I am unable to find the problem.

Below is sample code:

```
@Controller
public class CheckAvailbiltyEmailController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/check",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewAjaxEmail(Map model){       

        return new ModelAndView("CheckEmailAvaliblity");        
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/check", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String ajaxEmailCheck(@RequestParam("email") String email){

        System.out.println("Email is:"+email);
        return "Please carry on registration";

    }
}
```

My Ajax code:

```
   $.ajax({          
        type:"POST",
        url:"/check"            
      success:function(data){
            alert("Inside Success");
            $('#resp email').html(data);
        } 
       error: function(e){

       }        
    });
```

Comment: Think you forgot your code @sateesh!

Comment: Your controller method is expecting an `email` request parameter. You need to pass this through in your AJAX method either as querystring or request body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the data you want to send to the server,
The controller will accept "email" as the RequestParam.

Do it like the following snippet :

```
$.ajax({          
    type:"POST",
    url:"/check",
    data: {"email":"email@to.check.com"},
    success:function(responseData){
        alert("Inside Success");
        $('#resp email').html(responseData);
    }, 
   error: function(e){

   }        
});
```

Comment: Hi Ferdinand,Thanks for response. My Main problem here is response not coming to Jsp. Returned String response from controller displayed on the browser like "Please carry on registration".

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for  response. My problem resolved by correcting jsp and ajax code.